# Push Notification Not Received In IOS Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Push notifications are working as expected in the android application however nothing is received in IOS. Test notifications are also being received in IOS successfully.

```
const payload = {
        data: {                                  
            'key': 'value'
        } 
    };
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationToken, payload)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stuck on this IOS requires notification to be included so your payload should have the following structure:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {                                  
        'title': 'value',
        'body': 'value'
    },
    data: {                                  
        'key': 'value'
    } 
};
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(notificationToken, payload)
```